# Hunting map for personal use (or to publish)

Tags: shapefile

Okay, I do not know anything about GIS. I just downloaded it today to try to get a jump start on my GIS experience for a class next semester. I want to start off by making something useful so I want to make a map of hunting spots that I use. Can someone tell me where I would begin?

Comment: Any particular location(s)?

Comment: In South Texas there's a lot of activity in both oil/gas leasing as well as hunting leases.  I wonder if hunting leases use the same sorts of legal descriptions.  Seems like if you had a big ranch you'd need to be careful about how you lease it out for hunting.  If so, maybe some of the same base layers could be used.

Comment: Montgomery county. Honestly if someone could even just tell me how to start a map that would be helpful

Comment: You said "I just downloaded [GIS] today" - what software and version did you download?  Once that is known I suspect our first advice will be whether you have looked for any tutorials on that product.

Comment: How about collecting with GPS of your cellphone the hunting spots you can use a free App. I recommend fulcrum http://fulcrumapp.com/. Then download your points and load them in whatever GIS you have and create a very simple location map